# Separate section number in headers

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I'm writing a book and want my separate odd and even headers, with centered chapter/section titles on even/odd pages respectively.  On both pages I want to print the section number on the outside of the page.

I thought this would be easy to do with, for example,

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\thesection}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thesection}
```

Unfortunately, this fails when a new section heading starts at the top of a page, in which case the previous page gets labelled with the new section number.  I know this happens because \thesection is expanded too late, but I want an easy fix.  Also, I can't use the \rightmark to store the section number because I'm using that to store the section name.

Here's a minimum working example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thesection}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection. #1}{}} 

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[2]

\section{Blah}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Should have a 1 on the right-hand side]

Comment: It isn't clear what headings you want, you mention chapters but your example uses `article`. Basically you need to use `\leftmark` or `\rightmark` (I can't tell which because of the uncertainty about chapters) and just discard everything after the space if you only want the number and not the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following extracts the section number from `\leftmark` that you are using for the full section title. The section number is identified as anything at the beginning until `.␣` is seen. Otherwise nothing is set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmarksection}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection. #1}{}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\leftmarksection}{%
  \begingroup
    \protected@edef\temp{\leftmark}%
    \expandafter\@leftmarksection\temp. \@nil
  \endgroup
}
\def\@leftmarksection#1. #2\@nil{%
  \def\temp{#2}%
  \ifx\temp\@empty
  \else
    #1%
  \fi  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Title page
\newpage  
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[2]  

\section{Blah}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it really works the best.  Both David's and my own answer run into problems if the section name is at all fancy.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want this, I'm not sure which mark you need in your real case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\expandafter\numberonly\romannumeral`\^^@\leftmark!!}
\def\numberonly#1. #2!!{#1}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection. #1}{}} 

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[2]

\section{Blah}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This, and @Heiko Oberdiek's answer suggest that I extract the section number from \leftmark.  Could one of you show me how to extract just the section title from \leftmark as well.  I only included the section number in \leftmark in my example to help illustrate the problem.  What I'm really after is an even-side header with <section-number> <chapter-title> and an odd-side header with <section-title> <section-number>.

Comment: @PatMorin copy the definition of `\numberonly` but use `#2` instead of `#1` as the definition body

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both David and Heiko for your answers.  I wanted a solution that I could understand, so I used the xstring package to implement unpacking the section number and title from the \leftmark:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\StrBehind{\leftmark}{+}}
\fancyhead[R]{\StrBefore{\leftmark}{+}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection+#1}{}} 

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[2]

\section{Blah}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```